# Sorted list is not printing: VBA to Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an array which is grabbing data from multiple worksheets to print out to a summary sheet in a single workbook. The array, when stepping through the code, appears to be grabbing the correct data through all sheets. The array should then save, at each pass through the loop, information to sorted lists.

Source data is composed of two side by side (horizontal) sections representing two workers. The data for each worker, in terms of formating is identical.

My lists are not printing to the summary page and there seems to be an issue with list.count. If I have list.count -1 then the for loop does not run at all. If I omit the -1 then I get a single pass of the loop.

What is the problem with either the arrays being stored in the list and/or the output of the lists to the summary sheet?

```
Dim arTemp
Dim arTemp1
Dim d As Date
Dim x As Long, Y As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim list As Object, list1 As Object

Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
Set list1 = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Summary" And ws.Name <> "SheetX" Then
        With ws
            For y = 3 to 7
                d=DateSerial(Year(.Cells(3,y)), Month(.Cells(3,y)),1
                If List.containskey(d) then
                    arTemp = list(d)
                    arTemp1 = list1(d)
                Else
                    ReDim arTemp(13)
                    ReDim arTemp1(13)
                End If
                arTemp(0) = arTemp(0) + .Cells(4,y)
                arTemp(1) = arTemp(1) + .Cells(5,y)
                arTemp(2) = arTemp(2) + .Cells(6,y)
                .
                .
                .
                arTemp(12) = arTemp(12) + .Cells(16,y)
                arTemp(13) = arTemp(13) + 1
                list(d) = arTemp

                arTemp1(0) = arTemp1(0) + .Cells(4,y + 11)
                arTemp1(1) = arTemp1(1) + .Cells(5,y + 11)
                arTemp1(2) = arTemp1(2) + .Cells(6,y + 11)
                .
                .
                .
                arTemp1(12) = arTemp1(12) + .Cells(16,y + 11)
                arTemp1(13) = arTemp1(13) + 1
                list1(d) = arTemp1
            Next
        End With
    End If
Next

With Worksheets("Summary")
    .Cells.Delete
    For x = 0 To list.Count - 1
        d = list.getkey(x)
        .Cells(x + 43, 1) = Year(d)
        .Cells(x + 43, 2) = Month(d)
        .Cells(x + 43, 3) = list(d)(0)
        .Cells(x + 43, 4) = list(d)(1)
        .
        .
        .
        .Cells(x +43, 15) = list(d)(12)
    Next

    For x = 0 To list.Count - 1
        d = list1.getkey(x)
        .Cells(x + 43, 1) = Year(d)
        .Cells(x + 43, 2) = Month(d)
        .Cells(x + 43, 3) = list1(d)(0)
        .Cells(x + 43, 4) = list1(d)(1)
        .
        .
        .
        .Cells(x +43, 15) = list1(d)(12)
    Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is an expansive spreadsheet, I narrowed my initial test field down to two arrays. The issue was that my list counters were not incrementing because they were pointing to a list which had, in my actual code, been commented out for testing purposes. As such, the subsequent lists (list1, list2, list3 ...) were limited to the number of records in the "initial" list. Therefore, there was nothing to trigger the For loops for data output: list.Count - 1 had no value so the For loop was skipped.

As each list has the same number of records, my initial condition was simply to use the first list's index as the bounds for all subsequent lists. However, this breaks if the first list is not run (during testing). The best solution is to have each list's for loop check for it's own individual bounds.

```
For x=0 to list.Count -1
  d=list.getkey(x)
  do stuff
Next

For X=0 to list1.Count-1
 d=list1.getkey(x)
 do stuff
Next
```